# Abrir app google maps via link pelo ionic 3

Tags: javascript, html5, ionic, google-maps, typescript

Preciso fazer um link que abra app externo do google maps no android e ios (apple maps) que abra com marcador em uma determinada coordenada.
Até o momento, pelas pesquisa achei algo semelhante ao apresentado aqui:

```
iOS (launching Apple Maps):
<a href="maps:?q=LOCATION" target="_system">Map</a>

iOS (launching Google Maps):
<a href="comgooglemaps://?q=LOCATION" target="_system">Map</a>

Android:
<a href="geo:?q=LOCATION" target="_system">Map</a>
```

O problema desse código é que não sei como formatar o location.
Alguém já passou por isso?

Answer (score 3):

```
<a href="geo:?q=LOCATION" target="_system">Map</a>
```

Onde LOCATION seria latitude e longitude

```
<a href="geo:?q=-22.9121089,-43.2301558" target="_system">Map</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

use o **Launch Navigator do Ionic v3** native... Usei ontem mesmo no meu projeto e deu tudo certo.
Funciona para UBER, GOOGLE MAPS, WAZE ETC... se você quer que o usuário escolha qual app de map ele deseja usar basta você não definir o:
app: LaunchNavigator.APPS.UBER
http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/launch-navigator/

Comment: Quero algo mais simples, somente o link no caso pra abrir o app Google Maps e setando a localização com marcador.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver.

```
Android:
<a href="geo:?q=LOCATION" target="_system">Map</a>
```

link: http://tebros.com/2016/02/launching-external-maps-app-from-ionic2/

Comment: Muito obrigado!